# How to insert records into table with variable as the name mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got two databases - one for restaurant users (user_reg), and one for the restaurant menu items (restaurant_menu).

One form stores this particular variable `$rname` in user_reg, which is the restaurant name. It then creates a table called `$rname` in restaurant_menu, with columns like item_name, category, price, etc.

What I want to do is insert records into the appropriate table of $rname, however since it is the specific user adding items, I need their items to go under the table for their specific restaurant name.

It works perfectly when I use a specific table name such as "kfc"

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO kfc (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES (('".$item_name."'), ('".$price."'), ('".$description."'), ('".$category."'), ('".$origin."'), ('".$sub_category."'))";
```

However this is what I have working:

```
$item_name = $_POST["item_name"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$origin = $_POST["origin"];
$sub_category = $_POST["sub_category"];

$rname = $_POST["rname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO $rname (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES (('".$item_name."'), ('".$price."'), ('".$description."'), ('".$category."'), ('".$origin."'), ('".$sub_category."'))";
```

It simply needs to record those inputted values into table $rname. Can this be done across two databases?

Comment: Your query is _wide open_ for SQL injection.  All any malicious user would have to do is pass in the table they want to target with the `rname` parameter, and off they go.  Any reason why you think the target table should be decided by the UI parameter?

Comment: Ignore all the 4 terrible answers here which are dengerous just like your current code. Read about prepared statements  in `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) tutorial , for inserting data in tables.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your sql variable

`$sql = "INSERT INTO $rname (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES ('$item_name', '$price', '$description', '$category', '$origin', '$sub_category'";`

I prefer the `mysqli_query($connectionhandler, $sql);` method

Answer (score 0):

/* Here we are going to use extract function which converts array key's into accessible variable. Not need to declare variables and store post value in that. However it's not good practice to send table name from User Interface It may leads to hack your system*/
Code showing here

```
extract($_POST);

$sql = "INSERT INTO $rname (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES ('$item_name','$price', '$description', '$category', '$origin', '$sub_category')";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, calling each value by it's variable would be best.

The syntax for inserting values is

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

So changes the values section to reflect the variables for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

for Mysql

```
$sql = mysql_query($dbconnectivity,("INSERT INTO $rname (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES ('$item_name', '$price', '$description', '$category', '$origin', '$sub_category')");
```

For Mysqli

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnectivity,("INSERT INTO $rname (item_name, price, description, category, origin, sub_category) VALUES ('$item_name', '$price', '$description', '$category', '$origin', '$sub_category')");
```

Comment: why `"mysqli_query(...)"`  is quoted `""` ?